# React.js, this.props.changeTitle is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a title and a textbox below it using React, ES6, Webpack and Babel. The content of the title changes/re-renders as we type inside the textbox.
There are primarily two files, Header.js and app.js
//app.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Header from "./Header/Header";
export default class App extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = ({title: "Welcome"});

    }

    changeTitle(newtitle)
    {
        this.setState({title: newtitle});
    }

    handleChange(e)
    {
        const input = e.target.value;
        this.props.changeTitle(input);
    }

    render()
    {
        return(
            <div>
                <Header  changeTitle = {this.changeTitle.bind(this)} title = {this.state.title}/>
                <input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
            </div>
            );
    }
}
    const element = document.getElementById('app');
    ReactDOM.render(<App/>,element); 
======================================================
//Header.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default class Header extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
            </div>
            );
    }
}
```

If I move the handleChange(e) method and `<input>` tag line from app.js to Header.js then it works fine, but otherwise I get error that "this.props.changeTitle is not a function", which is inside handleChange(e) method.

Comment: If someone answered your question correctly, click the empty checkmark next to the answer to mark it correct. Otherwise, update the question.

Comment: What a pleasant surprise 1.5 years later

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA. Never give up hope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass a prop to `<App />` called changeTitle when you render it `ReactDOM.render(<App/>,element);`

It looks like you just want `this.changeTitle` instead of `this.props.changeTitle`

Answer (score 1):

Theres no need to pass the function `changeTitle()` to the `<Header/>` just have `handleChange()` call `this.setState()`.

```
handleChange(e)
{
    const input = e.target.value;
    this.setState({title: input});
}

render()
{
    return(
        <div>
            <Header title = {this.state.title}/>
            <input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        </div>
        );
}
```

React will rerender `<App/>` which in turn will rerender() `<Header/>`